# Repotting my cactus

Tags: repotting

This cactus has so many "babies". I need to report because the planter is broken.
Can I separate the babies and plant them without the "mom". Or should I keep them all together?[image]

Comment: Do whichever you want. If you want to separate them, gently break them off the main plant. Don't try to cut them. You will be left with a scar on the main plant, if that might bother you. If you leave them lying on their sides in good light for a few days (with no water - they won't die!) they will probably start to grow roots, and then you can pot them up. If you pot them before they start to grow, don't plant them too deep, and be careful not to over-water them until they are growing, otherwise they may start to rot.